# Alter table column while the table is in use

Tags: web-sql

I am using WebSQL. I have needed to change the field data type. A problem is currently a number of users using the application & they have data on the table.

**Table**: customers

**Field**: address         (current data type: UNIQUE)

I have tried with

```
var db = openDatabase("myDb", "1.0", "My Database", 100000);
if(db.version === "1.0"){
  db.changeVersion("1.0", "2.0", function(t){
    t.executeSql("ALTER TABLE customers ALTER COLUMN address TEXT");
  });
}
```

It executes but no change happens. I need to change the column data type without affecting the current users of application's data.

Comment: Not clear your comment. address address!!!!!

Comment: ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY address text